# Деление больших чисел

Tags: java

Как получить Biginteger с дробной частью? Т.е.  237383920029282727273637282920108273.917171617181919292926262618

Comment: Integer - целое число (дословный перевод)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго дня!

Попробуйте использовать BigDecimal

Comment: BigInteger a= new BigInteger("10");
  BigInteger b= new BigInteger("3");
  BigDecimal r=new  BigDecimal( a.divide(b));  выводит r=3, а нужно 3,33333333333

Comment: Вы делите целое на целое, получится целое. А результат вы преобразуете в BigDecimal. Делитель и делимое уже должны иметь тип BigDecimal

Comment: Например так new BigDecimal("10").divide(new BigDecimal("3"), new MathContext(10, RoundingMode.DOWN))